# How can I convert YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00+00:00 in BigQuery?

Tags: regex, date, google-bigquery

I have a column filled with dates in the "standard SQL" format (YYYYMMDD), but I need it to be in the format accepted by CartoDB (YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00+00:00).

My initial thought was that BQ would have a function similar to to_datetime(variable, format), but it doesn't appear to.

My second thought is that I should use a regex, but BQ uses [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). I have no experience with RE2 and can't parse the documentation. Could somebody with more experience with RE2 help me out, or recommend a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below
BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT
  x,
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(x, '%Y-%m-%d') + 'T00:00:00+00:00' AS y
FROM
(SELECT '20160526' AS x)
```

BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT
  x,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E6S%z", PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", x )) AS y
FROM
(SELECT '20160526' AS x)
```

Comment: FORMAT_TIMESTAMP isn't recognized as a function.

STRFTIME_UTC_USEC is, but is simply returning "1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00". I tried replacing '%Y-%m-%d' with '%Y%m%d' (since my format is YYYYMMDD), but to no avail.

Comment: Please note: second example is for BigQuery Standard SQL version - you should unckeck Use Legacy SQL checkbox under Show Options in Web UI. Try again - it DOES work :o)

Comment: what data type of this column? as you can see i am using string in my example. if it is not string in your data - just provide small example of it with datatype

Comment: I've switched over and it now appears to be working, although I need to change some other statements which don't comply with BQ Standard (such as rand()). It is indeed a string

Comment: My mistake, it's actually an integer, not a string. That changes a lot

Comment: Quick Q, in the non-legacy version, what is the proper format for the FROM statement? I have it as "FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.events]", but I guess that's legacy?

Comment: 'Projectile.datasetid.tableid'

Comment: \`gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.events` to be exact